# Font embedding in Opera Speed Dial Extension

Tags: css, fonts, opera, google-font-api, opera-extension

I'm making a Speed Dial extension for Opera 15+ (the Webkit-based ones) and I want to embed a custom font.

Now, I'm quite used to embed fonts using Google Fonts, but as far [as documentation says](http://dev.opera.com/extension-docs/tut_architecture_overview.html) this is not possible because of security concerns. Then, I think I need to load fonts locally using @font-face, but I don't know which formats Opera 15+ (or Webkit, by default) accepts and how to actually embed it in my CSS.

Is there a way to find out what kind of font embedding I can use? Are Speed Dial extensions not allowed to have custom fonts? Can I use Google Fonts directly? Those are my questions.

Answer (score 0):

woff is the format you need

using google fonts probably won't be available